# Why does updating our database take so long?

Tags: mysql, upsert

I currently have a small app take in a CSV and call a procedure to update/insert records to keep our MySQL 5.6.39 database up to date with the database of an external web app we use (that we don't have direct access or control over). We update weekly and right now it can take most of a day to finish (~60,000 records), so I have to speed things up somehow.

This is one of the procedure's we use:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `upsert-debtors` (
    internalCaseIDParam VARCHAR(50),
    caseNumberParam VARCHAR(50),
    bankruptcyCaseNumberParam VARCHAR(50),
    bankruptcyChapterNumberParam VARCHAR(50),
    bankruptcyDateFiledParam VARCHAR(50),
    bankruptcyDischargeDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    bankruptcyDismissalDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    accountReceivedDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    clientCommissionRateParam VARCHAR(50),
    clientFullNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    clientNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    collectionStatusDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    collectorUserNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    creditorParam VARCHAR(50),
    currentBalanceDueParam VARCHAR(50),
    currentClaimStatusParam VARCHAR(50),
    currentCostsParam VARCHAR(50),
    currentFeesParam VARCHAR(50),
    currentInterestParam VARCHAR(50),
    currentPerDiemParam VARCHAR(50),
    currentPrincipalParam VARCHAR(50),
    dateEnteredInSimplicityParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorAkaParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorAddressOneParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorAddressTwoParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorAddressStatusParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorCellParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorCityParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorCompanyContactParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorCompanyNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorDobParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorEmailParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorFaxParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorFirstNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorFullNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorLastNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorLinkedBalanceParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorMiddleNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorOtherPhoneParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorPhoneParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorPrefixParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorSSNParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorStateParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorSuffixParam VARCHAR(50),
    debtorZipParam VARCHAR(50),
    docketNumberParam VARCHAR(50),
    employerNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    employerPhoneParam VARCHAR(50),
    firstDelinquencyDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    hotZipParam VARCHAR(50),
    importNotesParam VARCHAR(250),
    lastAccessDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    lastDateReportedToEquifaxParam VARCHAR(50),
    lastDateReportedToExperianParam VARCHAR(50),
    lastDateReportedToTransunionParam VARCHAR(50),
    lastPaymentAmountParam VARCHAR(50),
    lastPaymentDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    lastPaymentNettedAmountParam VARCHAR(50),
    lastWorkDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    neverReportToCreditBureausParam VARCHAR(50),
    nextWorkDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    oldSysAcctSParam VARCHAR(50),
    isClosedParam VARCHAR(50),
    originalClaimAmountParam VARCHAR(50),
    originalClaimInterestRateParam VARCHAR(50),
    originatedDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    patientParam VARCHAR(50),
    patientDobParam VARCHAR(50),
    patientSsnParam VARCHAR(50),
    payerParam VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanAmount1Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanAmount2Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanAmount3Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanAmount4Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanAmount5Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanAmount6Param VARCHAR(50),
    nextPaymentPlanDueAmountParam VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanDate1Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanDate2Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanDate3Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanDate4Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanDate5Param VARCHAR(50),
    paymentPlanDate6Param VARCHAR(50),
    nextPaymentPlanDueDateParam VARCHAR(50),
    pmtPlanOverdueParam VARCHAR(50),
    physicianParam VARCHAR(50),
    pifCatalystParam VARCHAR(50),
    referringAttorneyNameParam VARCHAR(50),
    totalAttorneyFeesParam VARCHAR(50),
    totalClaimAmountParam VARCHAR(50),
    totalCostsParam VARCHAR(50),
    totalInterestParam VARCHAR(50),
    totalPaymentsParam VARCHAR(50),
    totalPaymentsPreAndPostParam VARCHAR(50),
    workflowBandParam VARCHAR(50),
    clientClaimNumberParam VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        debtors
    SET
        case_number = caseNumberParam,
        bankruptcy_case_number = bankruptcyCaseNumberParam,
        bankruptcy_chapter_number = bankruptcyChapterNumberParam,
        bankruptcy_date_filed = bankruptcyDateFiledParam,
        bankruptcy_discharge_date = bankruptcyDischargeDateParam,
        bankruptcy_dismissal_date = bankruptcyDismissalDateParam,
        account_received_date = accountReceivedDateParam,
        client_commission_rate = clientCommissionRateParam,
        client_full_name = clientFullNameParam,
        client_name = clientNameParam,
        collection_status_date = collectionStatusDateParam,
        collector_user_name = collectorUserNameParam,
        creditor = creditorParam,
        current_balance_due = currentBalanceDueParam,
        current_claim_status = currentClaimStatusParam,
        current_costs = currentCostsParam,
        current_fees = currentFeesParam,
        current_interest = currentInterestParam,
        current_per_diem = currentPerDiemParam,
        current_principal = currentPrincipalParam,
        date_entered_in_simplicity = dateEnteredInSimplicityParam,
        debtor_aka = debtorAkaParam,
        debtor_address_one = debtorAddressOneParam,
        debtor_address_two = debtorAddressTwoParam,
        debtor_address_status = debtorAddressStatusParam,
        debtor_cell = debtorCellParam,
        debtor_city = debtorCityParam,
        debtor_company_contact = debtorCompanyContactParam,
        debtor_company_name = debtorCompanyNameParam,
        debtor_dob = debtorDobParam,
        debtor_email = debtorEmailParam,
        debtor_fax = debtorFaxParam,
        debtor_first_name = debtorFirstNameParam,
        debtor_full_name = debtorFullNameParam,
        debtor_last_name = debtorLastNameParam,
        debtor_linked_balance = debtorLinkedBalanceParam,
        debtor_middle_name = debtorMiddleNameParam,
        debtor_other_phone = debtorOtherPhoneParam,
        debtor_phone = debtorPhoneParam,
        debtor_prefix = debtorPrefixParam,
        debtor_s_s_n = debtorSSNParam,
        debtor_state = debtorStateParam,
        debtor_suffix = debtorSuffixParam,
        debtor_zip = debtorZipParam,
        docket_number = docketNumberParam,
        employer_name = employerNameParam,
        employer_phone = employerPhoneParam,
        first_delinquency_date = firstDelinquencyDateParam,
        hot_zip = hotZipParam,
        import_notes = importNotesParam,
        last_access_date = lastAccessDateParam,
        last_date_reported_to_equifax = lastDateReportedToEquifaxParam,
        last_date_reported_to_experian = lastDateReportedToExperianParam,
        last_date_reported_to_transunion = lastDateReportedToTransunionParam,
        last_payment_amount = lastPaymentAmountParam,
        last_payment_date = lastPaymentDateParam,
        last_payment_netted_amount = lastPaymentNettedAmountParam,
        last_work_date = lastWorkDateParam,
        never_report_to_credit_bureaus = neverReportToCreditBureausParam,
        next_work_date = nextWorkDateParam,
        old_sys_acct_s = oldSysAcctSParam,
        is_closed = isClosedParam,
        original_claim_amount = originalClaimAmountParam,
        original_claim_interest_rate = originalClaimInterestRateParam,
        originated_date = originatedDateParam,
        patient = patientParam,
        patient_dob = patientDobParam,
        patient_ssn = patientSsnParam,
        payer = payerParam,
        payment_plan_amount_1 = paymentPlanAmount1Param,
        payment_plan_amount_2 = paymentPlanAmount2Param,
        payment_plan_amount_3 = paymentPlanAmount3Param,
        payment_plan_amount_4 = paymentPlanAmount4Param,
        payment_plan_amount_5 = paymentPlanAmount5Param,
        payment_plan_amount_6 = paymentPlanAmount6Param,
        next_payment_plan_due_amount = nextPaymentPlanDueAmountParam,
        payment_plan_date_1 = paymentPlanDate1Param,
        payment_plan_date_2 = paymentPlanDate2Param,
        payment_plan_date_3 = paymentPlanDate3Param,
        payment_plan_date_4 = paymentPlanDate4Param,
        payment_plan_date_5 = paymentPlanDate5Param,
        payment_plan_date_6 = paymentPlanDate6Param,
        next_payment_plan_due_date = nextPaymentPlanDueDateParam,
        pmt_plan_overdue = pmtPlanOverdueParam,
        physician = physicianParam,
        pif_catalyst = pifCatalystParam,
        referring_attorney_name = referringAttorneyNameParam,
        total_attorney_fees = totalAttorneyFeesParam,
        total_claim_amount = totalClaimAmountParam,
        total_costs = totalCostsParam,
        total_interest = totalInterestParam,
        total_payments = totalPaymentsParam,
        total_payments_pre_and_post = totalPaymentsPreAndPostParam,
        workflow_band = workflowBandParam,
        client_claim_number = clientClaimNumberParam
    WHERE internal_case_id = internalCaseIDParam;

    IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO
          debtors (
            internal_case_id,
            case_number,
            bankruptcy_case_number,
            bankruptcy_chapter_number,
            bankruptcy_date_filed,
            bankruptcy_discharge_date,
            bankruptcy_dismissal_date,
            account_received_date,
            client_commission_rate,
            client_full_name,
            client_name,
            collection_status_date,
            collector_user_name,
            creditor,
            current_balance_due,
            current_claim_status,
            current_costs,
            current_fees,
            current_interest,
            current_per_diem,
            current_principal,
            date_entered_in_simplicity,
            debtor_aka,
            debtor_address_one,
            debtor_address_two,
            debtor_address_status,
            debtor_cell,
            debtor_city,
            debtor_company_contact,
            debtor_company_name,
            debtor_dob,
            debtor_email,
            debtor_fax,
            debtor_first_name,
            debtor_full_name,
            debtor_last_name,
            debtor_linked_balance,
            debtor_middle_name,
            debtor_other_phone,
            debtor_phone,
            debtor_prefix,
            debtor_s_s_n,
            debtor_state,
            debtor_suffix,
            debtor_zip,
            docket_number,
            employer_name,
            employer_phone,
            first_delinquency_date,
            hot_zip,
            import_notes,
            last_access_date,
            last_date_reported_to_equifax,
            last_date_reported_to_experian,
            last_date_reported_to_transunion,
            last_payment_amount,
            last_payment_date,
            last_payment_netted_amount,
            last_work_date,
            never_report_to_credit_bureaus,
            next_work_date,
            old_sys_acct_s,
            is_closed,
            original_claim_amount,
            original_claim_interest_rate,
            originated_date,
            patient,
            patient_dob,
            patient_ssn,
            payer,
            payment_plan_amount_1,
            payment_plan_amount_2,
            payment_plan_amount_3,
            payment_plan_amount_4,
            payment_plan_amount_5,
            payment_plan_amount_6,
            next_payment_plan_due_amount,
            payment_plan_date_1,
            payment_plan_date_2,
            payment_plan_date_3,
            payment_plan_date_4,
            payment_plan_date_5,
            payment_plan_date_6,
            next_payment_plan_due_date,
            pmt_plan_overdue,
            physician,
            pif_catalyst,
            referring_attorney_name,
            total_attorney_fees,
            total_claim_amount,
            total_costs,
            total_interest,
            total_payments,
            total_payments_pre_and_post,
            workflow_band,
            client_claim_number
          )
        VALUES
          (         
            internalCaseIDParam,
            caseNumberParam,
            bankruptcyCaseNumberParam,
            bankruptcyChapterNumberParam,
            bankruptcyDateFiledParam,
            bankruptcyDischargeDateParam,
            bankruptcyDismissalDateParam,
            accountReceivedDateParam,
            clientCommissionRateParam,
            clientFullNameParam,
            clientNameParam,
            collectionStatusDateParam,
            collectorUserNameParam,
            creditorParam,
            currentBalanceDueParam,
            currentClaimStatusParam,
            currentCostsParam,
            currentFeesParam,
            currentInterestParam,
            currentPerDiemParam,
            currentPrincipalParam,
            dateEnteredInSimplicityParam,
            debtorAkaParam,
            debtorAddressOneParam,
            debtorAddressTwoParam,
            debtorAddressStatusParam,
            debtorCellParam,
            debtorCityParam,
            debtorCompanyContactParam,
            debtorCompanyNameParam,
            debtorDobParam,
            debtorEmailParam,
            debtorFaxParam,
            debtorFirstNameParam,
            debtorFullNameParam,
            debtorLastNameParam,
            debtorLinkedBalanceParam,
            debtorMiddleNameParam,
            debtorOtherPhoneParam,
            debtorPhoneParam,
            debtorPrefixParam,
            debtorSSNParam,
            debtorStateParam,
            debtorSuffixParam,
            debtorZipParam,
            docketNumberParam,
            employerNameParam,
            employerPhoneParam,
            firstDelinquencyDateParam,
            hotZipParam,
            importNotesParam,
            lastAccessDateParam,
            lastDateReportedToEquifaxParam,
            lastDateReportedToExperianParam,
            lastDateReportedToTransunionParam,
            lastPaymentAmountParam,
            lastPaymentDateParam,
            lastPaymentNettedAmountParam,
            lastWorkDateParam,
            neverReportToCreditBureausParam,
            nextWorkDateParam,
            oldSysAcctSParam,
            isClosedParam,
            originalClaimAmountParam,
            originalClaimInterestRateParam,
            originatedDateParam,
            patientParam,
            patientDobParam,
            patientSsnParam,
            payerParam,
            paymentPlanAmount1Param,
            paymentPlanAmount2Param,
            paymentPlanAmount3Param,
            paymentPlanAmount4Param,
            paymentPlanAmount5Param,
            paymentPlanAmount6Param,
            nextPaymentPlanDueAmountParam,
            paymentPlanDate1Param,
            paymentPlanDate2Param,
            paymentPlanDate3Param,
            paymentPlanDate4Param,
            paymentPlanDate5Param,
            paymentPlanDate6Param,
            nextPaymentPlanDueDateParam,
            pmtPlanOverdueParam,
            physicianParam,
            pifCatalystParam,
            referringAttorneyNameParam,
            totalAttorneyFeesParam,
            totalClaimAmountParam,
            totalCostsParam,
            totalInterestParam,
            totalPaymentsParam,
            totalPaymentsPreAndPostParam,
            workflowBandParam,
            clientClaimNumberParam
          );
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Is there anything as far as the procedure is set up or possibly some database settings that would cause it to be as slow as it is?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there an index on debtors.internal_case_id?

Comment: Your DML (`CREATE TABLE...`) might be of use here? What's the average size of a record in your debtors table? The number of fields is getting a little on the large size for my tastes. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Additional information request after WEEKLY UPDATE complete. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after WEEKLY UPDATE completed,
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
lscpu    for CPU MHZ, core count +
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a     for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: Additional information request,  A) SHOW CREATE TABLE debtors;  B) SHOW INDEX FROM debtors;

Comment: Please post results of A) SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_instances; B) SELECT @@innodb_io_capacity_max; and C) SELECT @@innodb_io_capacity;   D) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%'; 
 E) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%';  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases are good at doing things en masse; they are slow at doing things one at a time.

1. LOAD DATA (or otherwise load the data) into a temporary table
2. Use IODKU:

   ```
   INSERT INTO debtors (...)
       SELECT ...
           FROM temp_table
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
   ```

To use IODKU, there needs to be a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY`) key so that it knows which row to test for the existence of.

Be sure to use `VALUES(col)` in the `UPDATE` part.  (See the documentation.)

You should seriously consider splitting that very-wide table into a few tables such as `bankruptcy`, `debtor`, `last_payment`, etc.  In doing so, you will quickly discover that you often don't need to update all hundred columns.

Also see what might reasonably be 'normalized'.  Both of these will make the IODKU step more complex.

`payment_plan` seems to have a limit of 6.  And probably has most rows empty.  It would be better to have the 6 as rows, not columns.  A particular debtor would have 0 or more rows, not limited to 6.

When you are running the update, does it interfere with other activities?  If so, chunk it into groups of 100 rows at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this procedure will be called for each internal_case_id. If you have thousands of internal_case_ids then calling this stored procedure for every one may be slower then if you convert it to a set based update statement.

For example if you could pull all the records from the csv into a temp table then you can join that table to your main table for your update statement, and you can have a separate insert statement for all internal_case_id that do not exist in your target table, calling the stored procedure once to achieve both.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the debtors table structure would be useful. Assuming internal_case_id isn't a unique or primary key you should make it become one.

As you are loading from a CSV file, a stored procedure for each entry and the code that runs through it isn't necessary as there is a [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) explicitly for this purpose.

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE 'file.csv' IGNORE
INTO debtors
...
```

Remove or un[] `LOCAL` depending on if the file is on the server or the client side.

The `IGNORE` is the important part of the syntax as it uses the UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY to not override existing internal_case_id entries in the same way as your stored procedure did.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to consider prior to your Weekly Update

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50;
```

to enable more in RAM storage of changes until weekly update is finished.

When done,

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size=25;
```

for default set aside.

Disclaimer:  I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Networkprofile,  additional suggestions and FREE Utility Scripts are available.